# How is full pivoting more stable than partial pivoting

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

I know the difference between partial and complete, and I've read that complete is more "stable" /  offers more "stability". In what sense is it more "stable"?

Comment: In this context "unstable" means "sensitive to roundoff errors". The solution to $Ax = b$ that you compute will differ from the true solution due to roundoff errors in the computer arithmetic operations. With full pivoting the effect of these roundoff errors tends to be less severe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a paper by Trefethen that describes the average case stability of Gaussian Elimination back in 1990 using random matrices. It does note at the beginning that average case analysis excludes worst-case possibilities. There are types of matrices mentioned at the beginning which have a large condition number with Gaussian [elimination.](https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2014/08/04/gaussian-elimination-with-partial-pivoting/) .You can generate these matrices in Matlab. Nick Higham created a bunch of test matrices. It looks like the following using python ( I don't have Matlab anymore).

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as slin
n=8 
# generate the matrix
A = np.eye(n,n)- np.tril(np.ones(n),-1)
A[:,n-1] = 1
P,L,U= slin.lu(A)
```

this generates the following matrix

```
A
Out[19]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [-1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [-1., -1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [-1., -1., -1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.]])

L
Out[20]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [-1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [-1., -1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [-1., -1., -1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  0.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.]])

U
Out[21]: 
array([[  1.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   1.],
       [  0.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   2.],
       [  0.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   4.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   8.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   0.,  16.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   0.,  32.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   1.,  64.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0., 128.]])
```

You can then test the residual error like this.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as slin
n=20 
# generate the matrix
A = np.eye(n,n)- np.tril(np.ones(n),-1)
A[:,n-1] = 1
P,L,U= slin.lu(A)

b = np.random.rand(n)

x = np.linalg.solve(A,b)
r = b - np.dot(A,x)

relative_residual = np.linalg.norm(r)/(np.linalg.norm(A)*np.linalg.norm(x))
```

keep on increasing the $n$ and see what happens.

How does full pivoting make it better? There is something called the growth factor denoted $\rho$

$$ \rho = \frac{\max_{i,j,k} | a_{j,k}^{k}|}{\max_{i,j} |a_{i,j}| } $$

where for a matrix $A$ the element $a_{i,j}^{k}$ denotes the element the matrix $A$ after the $k$th step in the elimination.  If $\rho$ is not too large then it will be deemed stable. The above matrix for partial pivoting has a growth factor of at least $2^{n-1}$ . You can see this through the matrix size being $n=8$. I.e $2^{8-1} =128$

So I believe when you test it in average case analysis it is almost the same however in the worst-case analysis you will have much worse residual error.